# UnmanagedMemoryStream disposal and memory leaks

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose, unmanagedresources

Considering the following code snippet and overlooking the lack of a *using* clause or an explicit disposal:

```
    public static Image GetImage(string imageName)
    {
        Image image = null;
        Stream unmanagedMemoryStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(imageName);
        image = Image.FromStream(unmanagedMemoryStream);
        return image;
    }
```

When will Dispose() be called on *unmanagedMemoryStream*? How would this change if the containing method was made non-static? Is a leak of unmanaged memory possible in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Jon's answer - changing the method to non-static will have no effect. The fact you have an Image local variable in a static method doesn't change anything - it's just a reference on the stack to an object on the heap. When the method exits, the reference is removed from the stack. So whether the method is static or not changes nothing in terms of memory leaking.

The possibility for memory leaking here is if the Image is never Disposed of and never Garbage Collected.

Comment: Marked as the answer because although Jon got there first, you answered all of my questions, not just the first one.

Answer (score 5):

When `image` is disposed, that will dispose of the stream - `Image.FromStream` effectively takes ownership of the stream it's given.

In particular, if you *did* dispose the stream in a `using` statement here, the image would be unusable, at least for some image types.